# Check if NSString have a negative bool value

Tags: ios, ios7, nsstring

In my recent app i receive a JSON and need to validate if the objet string is actually a bool value or a normal string.

I know the **NSString class** has a method `boolValue`. However this is method returns **NO** either if founded a negative bool value or not a valid bool value.

However i need to have different behaviors in my app if the string is really a bool value or a normal string, because the JSON can have both scenario.

Any idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: So basically you want to know if the string is either `1` or `0`, `true` or `false`, or `yes` or `no`?

Comment: Yes, basically. But i wanted to check if i can avoid a "check cycle" to validate the content instead of the object type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BOOL` from JSON will actually be wrapped in an `NSNumber` so it's as simple as checking the class of the object.

```
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    BOOL value = [object boolValue];
}
```

Comment: This, of course, assuming you've already passed this through `NSJSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create a NSString category and add a method `isJSONBoolean`

```
@implementation NSString (JSONBoolean)

-(BOOL) isJSONBoolean
{
    return [self isEqualToString:@"false"] || [self isEqualToString:@"true"]
    || [self isEqualToString:@"NO"] || [self isEqualToString:@"YES"]
    || [self isEqualToString:@"0"] || [self isEqualToString:@"1"];
}

@end
```

Feel free to change it according to the values you need to test.

Comment: Your solution will work, but i prefer to check the the object instead of the content. I thin shier solution is more clear. Thanks

Comment: This solution is more for the, unfortunately all too common, scenario where the backend isn't actually providing a boolean in the response but string encoding some sort of boolean representation.

Comment: By reading your question I though you had a NSString object after unserialising your JSON.